# How are constructor calls decided in Java?

Tags: java

I have a Java class where there are two parameterized constructors

```
public class TestApplication {

    TestApplication(Object o)
        {
            System.out.println("Object");
        }

        TestApplication(double[] darray)
        {
            System.out.println("Array");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new TestApplication(null);
        }
}
```

When I run this program I get output as "Array". Why does the Object constructor not run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor overloading resolution behaves the same as method overloading resolution. When two constructors match the passed parameter, the one with the more specific argument types is chosen.

`null` can be assigned to both a `double[]` and an `Object`, since both are reference types, but an array is a more specific type than `Object` (since arrays are sub-classes of the `Object` class), so `new TestApplication(null)` triggers the `TestApplication(double[] darray)` constructor.